# Gmail: How do I select a number of emails and then reply to them all with a canned response?

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

There are dozens of emails in my Gmail mailbox which I need to reply and I know what to reply just from reading subject. 
So, how do I select a number of emails and then reply to them all with a canned response?
Preferably in few clicks.

Comment: Welcome! This would fit better on the webapps Stack Exchange. It will likely be moved there. Please read the help center to see which topics are appropriate for Super User.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a plugin that gives you that ability.  Check out this link.

[Batch Reply For Gmail Makes Replying To Similar Emails Simple](http://lifehacker.com/5935294/batch-reply-for-gmail-makes-replying-to-similar-emails-simple)

Of course this is for Chrome users.